# Typegoose classes as types?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I have a client class which I want to have use my typegoose model. I understand how to use it, I'm just struggling to manage to get the types and intellisense to work with it. I export the class as `MemberClass` and the model as `Member`. Here's a sample piece, I'm just struggling to fill in the blanks

```js
// imports...
// the extended class is another client from a package
export class Client extends Client {
  memberData: // What goes here? (The type)

  constructor(){
    this.memberData = // And here?
  }

  async test(){
    console.log(this.memberData.findOne(...)) //and is this right?
  }
}
```

Any help welcome! I can provide the entire files if requested

Answer (score 0):

if you need examples on how to make an typegoose class, you can look into the [documentation](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/guides/quick-start-guide/)

some things to note:
- if you extend an class from an package that dosnt use typegoose, the properties will not be in the model (because no `@prop` got applied)
- classes with the same name should be avoided (or use [`customName`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/modelOptions/#customname))
- the constructor will **not** be executed by typegoose

> `memberData: // What goes here? (The type)`

without telling what this value should be, it is impossible to say the type